# Validates resource references inside android xml files Android

Tags: android, xml, google-maps

Here is my manifest of how i declared my MapsActivity

```
<activity android:name=".MapsActivity"/>
```

It still shows an error **Validates resource references inside android xml files Android** And the activity crashes. Here is my MapsActivity

```
package com.todaysfuture.autometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MapsActivity extends Fragment implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

/*
 * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
 * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
 */
private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

private TextView tvStartRide;
private TextView tvStopRide;

private Location startingLocation;
private Location endingLocation;

private String origin = null ;
private String destination = null ;

private Location location1 ;
private Location location2 ;

private LatLng loc1 ;
private LatLng loc2 ;

private float distance = 0 ;
private float fare = 0 ;

private double startLatitude ;
private double startLongitude ;
private double endLatitude ;
private double endLongitude ;
private float[] results ;

public MapsActivity(){

}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);

    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds

    tvStartRide = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.startRideText);
    tvStopRide = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.stopRideText);

    tvStopRide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    tvStartRide.setOnClickListener(startRideOnClickListener);
    tvStopRide.setOnClickListener(stopRideOnClickListener);

    return view;


}

View.OnClickListener startRideOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        tvStartRide.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tvStopRide.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        startingLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        location1 = startingLocation ;

        startLatitude = location1.getLatitude();
        startLongitude = location1.getLongitude();

        loc1 = new LatLng(startLatitude, startLongitude) ;

        try {
            origin = retrieveAddress(startingLocation) ;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ride starting from: " + origin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

View.OnClickListener stopRideOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        endingLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        try {
            destination = retrieveAddress(endingLocation) ;
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Ride ended at: " + destination, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        fare = calculateFare(distance) ;


    }
};

public String retrieveAddress(Location location) throws IOException {

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getActivity(), Locale.getDefault());

    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Here 1 represent max location result to returned, by documents it recommended 1 to 5

    String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // If any additional address line present than only, check with max available address lines by getMaxAddressLineIndex()
    /*String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
    String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
    String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
    String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode(); */
    String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Only if available else return NULL

    if (address != null)
        return address;
    else if (knownName != null)
        return knownName;
    else
        return null;
}

public void drawPolyline(LatLng location1, LatLng location2){

    Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(location1, location2)
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.RED));
}

/*@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    // Create the LocationRequest object
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
            .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
} */

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
 * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
 * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
 * <p/>
 * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
 * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
 * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
 * <p/>
 * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
 * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
 * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
 * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
 * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
 */
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        //mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

/**
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
 * just add a marker near Africa.
 * <p/>
 * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
 */
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));

}

private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

    double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
    double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title("I am here!");
    mMap.addMarker(options);
    //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 14.0f));

    if (location2 == null) {

        location2 = location ;
        loc2 = latLng ;

        endLatitude = loc2.latitude ;
        endLongitude = loc2.longitude ;

        //drawPolyline(loc1, loc2);

        //android.location.Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);

        //if ( results != null )
        //distance += results[0] ;

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Distance: " + distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    else {

        loc1 = loc2 ;
        loc2 = latLng ;

        startLatitude = loc1.latitude ;
        startLongitude = loc1.longitude ;

        endLatitude = loc2.latitude ;
        endLongitude = loc2.longitude ;

        drawPolyline(loc1, loc2);

        android.location.Location.distanceBetween(startLatitude, startLongitude, endLatitude, endLongitude, results);

        distance += results[0] ;

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Distance: " + distance, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (location == null) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    } else {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Oops!");
    builder.setMessage("An error occurred.");
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
     * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
     * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
     * error.
     */
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(getActivity(), CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        /*
         * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
         * user with the error.
         */

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Oops!");
        builder.setMessage("An error occurred.");
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    handleNewLocation(location);
}

public float calculateFare(float distance) {

    float distanceInkm = distance/1000 ;
    float firstTwokm = 2 ;
    float restOfDistance = distanceInkm - firstTwokm ;

    if (distanceInkm >= firstTwokm)
    {
        fare = 25 ;

        while (restOfDistance>=0) {

            fare += 0.8 ;
            restOfDistance -= 0.1 ;

        }

        return fare ;
    }

    else {

        while (distanceInkm>=0) {

            fare += 1.25 ;
            distanceInkm -= 0.1 ;
        }

        return fare ;
    }
}

}
```

What could be the solution? It is extending a fragment hence it should still be an activity. When i hover the cursor on the declare of the activity in the manifest it says 'com.todaysfuture.autometer.MapsActivity' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity'

Comment: extends `Activity` instead of `Fragment `

Comment: Umm. no. It extends a fragment only